# Invalid Header Value Error when creating boto3 sts client

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, botocore

I was authenticating with an internal IDP and then using the SAML assertion to assume role using with boto3 sts client. Interaction with IDP was fine and able to generate the SAML assertion after successful authentication but when I tried to generate the sts client "client = boto3.client('sts')" botocore threw Invalid header value error.

Error was coming from our egress proxy server.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aws_authentication/credentials.py", line 219, in decode_saml_assertion
    client = boto3.client('sts')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 93, in client
    return _get_default_session().client(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/boto3/session.py", line 258, in client
    return self._session.create_client(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 826, in create_client
    credentials = self.get_credentials()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 430, in get_credentials
    self._credentials = self._components.get_component(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 1975, in load_credentials
    creds = provider.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 1028, in load
    metadata = fetcher.retrieve_iam_role_credentials()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 486, in retrieve_iam_role_credentials
    role_name = self._get_iam_role(token)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 518, in _get_iam_role
    return self._get_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 427, in _get_request
    response = self._session.send(request.prepare())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 356, in send
    raise HTTPClientError(error=e)

botocore.exceptions.HTTPClientError: An HTTP Client raised an unhandled exception: Invalid header value b'---- proxy error response ----'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurred because in the botocore package _fetch_metadata_token function [Link](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/7c5f1e503b5295d87765c4d4097e0e0a2d31bb16/botocore/utils.py#L366) is connecting to the url http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token [Link](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/7c5f1e503b5295d87765c4d4097e0e0a2d31bb16/botocore/utils.py#L368) for fetching the metadata token.

To connect to 169.254.169.254 successfully I have add it to no_proxy so that egress proxy_server don't block the connection.

```
no_proxy=localhost,169.254.169.254
```

After adding metadata endpoint 169.254.169.254 to no_proxy, I was able to connect to sts and generate the client.